# Datatables is completely messed up and is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Below is a UI Screenshot of the datables.

[image]

I seriously don't know what am doing wrong. Can someone point the mistake am doing. The code attached here is segregated from different files. Am not able to figure out what is the mistake am doing.

```
   <head>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $(".example").dataTable();

      });
    </script>

    </head>

<body>
    <div class="roles_table" >
                    <table class="example" id="mytable">
                       <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Roles</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                       </thead> 
                       <tbody>
                  <?php foreach($resultRoles as $r) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r->cptv_role; ?></td>
                            <td></td>  
                        </tr>
                  <?php } ?>     
                       </tbody>
                    </table>  

      </div>

    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/index_admin_db.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Comment: The stylesheet is missing: https://datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: Did you have the link to the datatable.css on your page?

Comment: i tried adding that also. but its still misaligned. This is the stylesheet right    https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Check if this `$resultRoles` is returning what is expected.

Comment: the contents in the images are from `$resultRoles`

Comment: Maybe `dataTable()` is being called before the table is populated.  Try wrapping the javascript in `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: nope even that is not working!!